# How to Add a Arrow to Spinner Drop Down?

Tags: java, android, mono, xamarin

I Have Added a spinner drop down and i want to add a arrow to it

something like this:https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrv1J0z4bnBqPyV6XdPcqU46P4Liw60tbntm1Z8WXyHA7K8PYBsg

And Yes I Know i have to add a background image with the style of arrow i want but here's the thing, The Arrow color needs to be changed depending on the user set color, So creating one arrow for each color is not really a solution

I had the idea of using one of those Hex arrow's in a textbox and change the color that way but not sure if that is the right way

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: i Tried adding the gingerbread spinner style in the XML file but that failed

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your **spinner code** for down arrow which you shown in your image link.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />
```